# Loading a third party dll in visual c++/qt application

Tags: c++, qt, dll, loadlibrary

I have  third party dlls that I need to use with my application. The interface is defined in the third party dlls and I have to make the interface call from my application. I have the function prototype of the interface, but no lib files or header files. It looks like loadlibrary should be used, but is it possible without the header files ? Is there a way to generate such header files? Would also greatly appreciate some explanation for the loadlibrary, as I am still grasping the idea yet.
Thanks!

Comment: Where are the prototypes if you don't have any header file for the DLL? -- You can generate the header file with notepad or any other text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load the library with the API function `LoadLibrary`. After loading the DLL you use `GetProcAddress` to get the entry point for a specific function.

If it's a C++ library, you may have to care for the decorated names. The tools *dumpbin* and *undname* may help to identify what is really exported by the DLL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [QLibrary::resolve()](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qlibrary.html#resolve) (or its static convenience brethren) to lookup a symbol in a DLL, and call it.